# Reset and Login Issues with C9500-48Y4C Switch

Tags: switch, cisco-catalyst, logging

I have a Cisco C9500-48Y4C Switch, but I forgot the login credentials while configuring it, which has resulted in me being unable to access the Switch. Could you please guide me on how to reset this Switch? Alternatively, if any of you have other methods to help me log in successfully, I would greatly appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Search for `Cisco 9500 password recovery`.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps and I think you will get access again. At the end don't forget to set a new password again.

1. Turn the switch off and on again. Press and hold the `Mode` button during boot until you see the `switch:` prompt.
2. Enter these commands:
   `switch:` flash_init
   `switch:` load_helper
3. Rename and reboot the switch:
   `switch:` rename flash:config.text flash:config.old
   `switch:` boot
4. Enable and update the password
   `Switch>` enable
   `Switch#` configure terminal
   `Switch(config)#` enable secret NEW_PASSWORD
5. Save the configuration:
   `Switch#` wr

Hope that helps
Alexios